# Electric field of a moving charge with Lorentz transormation

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I was going through this link

http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/mrr/MRRtalk.html

There it says

> Now consider the electrostatic field of a point charge at rest, shown
>   at left below. At every point on the circle (actually a sphere), the
>   field has the same strength and points directly away from the
>   particle.
>
> [image]
>
> Field of a point charge, at rest and moving to the right If we put
>   this system in motion to the right (shown at right), two things
>   happen. The first is that the sphere gets length-contracted, flattened
>   in the direction of motion. The second is that the components of the
>   field perpendicular to the motion get stretched by the very same
>   Lorentz factor. Therefore the field still points directly away from
>   the point charge, but it's not the same in all directions: it's weaker
>   in front of and behind the particle, and stronger to the sides, as
>   shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> Field vectors around a point charge moving to the right

But I am not able to understand why the field perpendicular to the motion of charge gets stretched? Isn't it completely independent of how the field in other direction spreads? Shouldn't the $y$ direction always have?

$\LARGE\frac{E}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^{2}}$

Comment: InQusitive : charge q _is_ frame independent. Moreover there's no such thing as a point charge, that's a mathematical idealization. And on top of that, the electron doesn't actually have an electric field. It has an _electromagnetic_ field. It isn't surrounded by some outward-pointing E field, and the positron isn't surrounded by some inward-pointing E-field. See section 11.10 of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics where he says "one should properly speak of the electromagnetic field Fμν rather than E or B separately".

Comment: @JohnDuffield: I just ordered that book an hour before :)

Comment: @InQusitive : noted. IMHO it's a pity that Jackson says this in section 11 as opposed to section 1. There's a similar theme in Purcell: give some chapters on electricity then some chapters on magnetism, and only then move on to electromagnetism. I think this can be misleading myself, and that it would be better to start with electromagnetism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stretching of the electric field comes explicitly from the Lorentz Transform acting on the electromagnetic field tensor. The discussion here may be useful: http://bado-shanai.net/Map%20of%20Physics/mopLorentzTransEMField.htm . A bit of knowledge of vector calculus and perhaps even tensors is required to appreciate this explanation for the transformation of the E and B fields.

Also, the statement that the field is  "weaker in front and back and stronger on the sides" doesn't make sense physically because the E and B fields parallel to the direction of motion are unaltered by a Lorentz transformation.